# How to parse array of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to change an array which contains multiple arrays into a form that I can use for an external API.

Example:

```
[ [44.5,43.2,45.1] , [42, 41.2, 48.1] ]
```

into

```
[ [44.5,42], [43.2,41.2] , [45.1, 48.1] ]
```

Currently my code runs as this, but doesn't work

```
var newArr= [];
var tempArr= [];

for(var key in data){
    tempArr.push(finalArr[key][key])
    newArr.push(tempArr)
 }
```

Is there some easier way to accomplish this without looping? I was thinking of maybe a map function but I'm not sure how to implement it here.

Comment: Are you always going to have an array with exactly two sub-arrays?

Comment: will there be just a pair of arrays in the input?

Comment: "without looping" — anytime you have a list of things, *something* has to iterate ("loop") through the list items. There's no escaping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transpose the arrays by reducing and mapping the values.

This works for any length.

```js
const transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []);

console.log(transpose([[44.5, 43.2, 45.1], [42, 41.2, 48.1]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very cool solution but, I afraid, to the detriment of readability

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
  [44.5, 43.2, 45.1],
  [42, 41.2, 48.1]
];
var result = arr[0].map(function (el, index) {
  return [el, arr[1][index]];
});
console.log(result);
```

But you have to be sure, that source arrays have same length.

Comment: `return arr.map(b => b[index]);` to generalize it to `n` arrays.